# How to make a countdown timer to run faster and faster after button press

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I am working on a simple game where the user is timed to answer a question.

After each correct question the user's time is reduced.

Right now, the user starts with a time of **10s**.

How to make my `countDownTimer` reduces the amount of time with let say **0.8** after each correct answer.

I have to mention that my timer adjusts a progress bar as well.

**This is my code now:**

```
...
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private long timer_length = 10*1000;
private long timer_interval = 500;
...
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
 mTrueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //is the user right? if pressing True button
            if(isMathProblemTrue == 1){
                //user is correct
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                generateMathProblem();
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                createNStartTimer();
            }else{
                //user is incorrect
                transferUserToStartScreen();
                mCountDownTimer.cancel(); // cancel
            }
        }
    });
}

 private void createNStartTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timer_length,timer_interval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/100);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            transferUserToStartScreen();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: (millisUntilFinished/100); - set the "100" to be variable. When wrong answer chosen, increase this variable by certain amount you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I want the progress bar to start from the beginning after each button press. If I do what you suggested the progress bar does not start from the beginning again.

Comment: When user is incorrect, close the timer, increase the "100" variable and start over the timer. But you also need to init that variable to 100, on the next question.